# Unable to switch scenes in JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a JavaFX application, and I'm encountering an issue where I'm unable to switch scenes from main-view.fxml to imported-page.fxml. I've tried several approaches, but none of them seem to work.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
// Setting OnDragDropped
    importPane.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        boolean success = false;
        if (db.hasFiles()) {
            success = true;
            // Handle the dropped files here
            for (File file : db.getFiles()) {
                // You can process the file here
                System.out.println("Dropped file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                imagesFile.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            // After processing the files, switch to the imported-page.fxml scene
            try {
                Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/advanceprogramproject/imported-page.fxml"));
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                Stage stage = (Stage) importPane.getScene().getWindow(); // Get the current stage
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("The Switch is Unsuccessful " + e);
            }
        }
        event.setDropCompleted(success);
        event.consume();
    });
```

I've tried to switch scenes from MainViewController when a file is dropped onto the application window, but it doesn't work as expected. I've also verified that the path to imported-page.fxml is correct.

Can someone please help me identify the issue and provide guidance on how to switch scenes correctly in my JavaFX application?

I've already try to check the path and fx:id in fxml, which are correct. But the there's still error occur " javafx.fxml.LoadException: ". I wish that i could drop the file in the importPane and then its will goes to the next scene which is importPage and still have the file path store.

Comment: “…it doesn't work as expected.”  How can you tell?  What were you expecting to see?  What did you see instead?  Did you encounter an exception?

Comment: Instead of `System.out.println("The Switch is Unsuccessful " + e);`, try `e.printStackTrace();` - it may give you more information. You can always `System.out.println` (or `System.err.println`) your own message before the stack trace. Even better than both (but requires a bit more effort), use logging.

Comment: Get the complete stack trace (as suggested in an earlier comment), and post it, formatted as code, in the question.

Comment: This is not related to the Switching of the scene. The problem is the loading of FXML.